# Amazon s3 upload using transfer manager waiting for long time if there is no network

Tags: android, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading videos to amazon s3 using Transfer manager.
After calling the upload method which is asynchronous  i am calling waitForUploadResult().

If the network is not available the flow is blocked until the network is restored. Even exceptions are not thrown if there is no network for a long time.

I need to get notified if network is not available for more than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

[TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) is backed by an [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html). You can configure the timeout of a S3 client by passing a customized [ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html) object to the client. I hope this will help.